# Accessing data from an async function in React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've been trying to figure out how to access the data I'm returning from an async function in React while also using Typescript. I'm getting really confused about data types and what I should put where. Hoping someone can help me out. Here is the code of my function making the request, and the function that's using that data:

```
async getLatLong(location: string): Promise<WeatherAPI> {
        const response = await axios.get<WeatherAPI>(`${this.latLongUrl}q=${location}`)

        return response.data;
    }
    
    async getWeather(location: string) {
        const latLong = this.getLatLong(location);

        console.log(latLong);
    }
```

And here's the code of the defined interface:

```
export interface WeatherAPI {
    country: string,
    lat: number,
    local_names: object,
    lon: number,
    name: string,
    state: string
}
```

I'm not getting an error with this code, but all it's logging is `Promise{<pending>}` instead of the data I'm expecting. If I try to change `console.log(latLong)` to `console.log(latLong[0])` as the data is an array, I get the error `Property '0' does not exist on type 'Promise<WeatherAPI>'.`

Comment: To access the eventual value of a promise, `await` that promise. So `const latLong = await this.getLatLong(location)`

Comment: @NicholasTower Thanks so much. If you want to put that as the answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One addition to the answer in the comment: you can also use `then` to handle the promise value:

```
getLatLong(location).then((latlong) => {...})
```

Same with `await`:

```
const latLong = await this.getLatLong(location)
```

Read more about promises in the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) if you're interested.